# Can't add guest session in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: users, guest-session, 18.10

So I just installed Ubuntu 18.10, but I can't add a guest account. there aren't any buttons for it. [image: users screen]

Comment: What options do you want for the guest account? For example no password-login?

Comment: Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

Comment: Also, while the dupe was the reason for removing Guest Session from LightDM in 16.04 - 17.04, 17.10 and newer use GDM, which doesn't support it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You must be logged as administrator, and click the green button "add user" and choose "standard" account type for guest user.

Comment: So there isn't a feature for guest sessions and  I just have to put a note by the computer saying, "guest password is {password]"?